# SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 Express Edition "Report Builder" Button

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder

How do I enable the "Report Builder" button on SQL Server Reporting Services (Report Manager Web View).

I am using the 2008 R2 Express Edition.

Is this available in this edition ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that this feature is not available in the express edition - you will also not be able to create a report model.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that it's possible. If you compare [Express to Standard](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx), expand the Reporting node, you will see Model Support is unchecked for Express. Report Builder 1.0 only worked on prebuilt models so by extension, I'm assuming that bullet continues to address models and the report builder.

I never install Express so I can't dig around and verify it.

If the Report Builder button is not showing, verify the accessing account has R[eport Builder role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157257.aspx) or better.  [Predefined SSRS Roles in 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157363.aspx)